# Find all pairs of prime numbers $p, q$ such that $p+q = 18(p−q)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Find all pairs of prime numbers $p, q$ such that $p+q = 18(p−q)$.

It is clear that $p-q$ must be an even number since if we consider $q$ as $2$, we won't get any solution. So any pair of odd prime does the work. I got $p=19$ and $q=17$ as one pair, considering the fact that $p+q$ must be a multiple of $18$. So considering numbers $18\cdot 2$, $18\cdot4$ , $18\cdot6$ ... as $p+q$ and then testing whether such pair of odd prime exist or not.

Is this the right approach since I am stuck up?

Answer (score 12):

$p+q = 18p - 18q$

$17p = 19q$

Therefore $p = 19n$ and $q=17n$.

Then $p$ and $q$ are prime only when $n=1$.

Hence the only solution in primes is $(p,q) = (19,17)$

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Logic is  right.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think yours is the best approach.

Observe that
$$ p + q = 18(p-q) \iff 17p = 19q $$

So $ p = 19, q = 17 $ satisfy this, but if $ p \neq 19 $, then $17p $ must be divisible by $ 19 $ and since $ \gcd(17,19) = 1$, so must be $ p $. This proves that $(17,19)$ is the only such pair

Answer (score 4):

You can write this as $$17p=19q$$
$$\implies \frac{p}{q}=\frac{19}{17}$$
But since $p,q$ are prime, the only possible solution is $p=19,q=17
$.

Answer (score 3):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Rearranging leads to $17p=19q$. This should suggest more to you. Note that $17$ and $19$ are prime.